# Avoid Snowflake sequence for being evaluated in case statement for unreachable condition

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, sequence

I am trying to assign an `id` when adding new data from table SOURCE to TARGET following the logic:

- if is updated data, than use the existing `id` from TARGET table
- if is new data, then generate new `id` using a Snowflake Sequence

Code looks like:

```
select case when ep.id is not null then ep.id else sequence.nextval
...
from SOURCE p left join TARGET ep  on p.otherKey = ep.otherKey;
```

My issue is that the sequence is always evaluated which means that the gaps between ids will be quite big giving that there are lots of updates and only a few new records.

Question: how can I change this `id` creation to still using the same sequence but to avoid calling the sequence every time?

Haven't tried anything as I don't know what would be possible in this situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to split data before calling the `sequence.nextval`:

```
SELECT ep.id
   ...
FROM SOURCE p 
INNER JOIN TARGET ep  
  ON p.otherKey = ep.otherKey
UNION ALL
SELECT sequence.nextval
   ...
FROM SOURCE p 
LEFT JOIN TARGET ep  
  ON p.otherKey = ep.otherKey
WHERE ep.OtherKey IS NULL;
```

Comment: I used a similar approach to this one in the end so I am accepting this. To avoid the UNION I created a `cte` with the new ids. Then in my case statement I either used the existing id or the one that would be found in my `cte` based on join between SOURCE and TARGET. This way I avoided the huge gaps and the union.

Answer (score 1):

At first glace, I was puzzled by this, as function calls placed in the second branch of "logic" are not called. So wrote some SQL to test the 4 logic types, (that are mostly the same code really):

```
create or replace sequence s1;
create or replace sequence s2;
create or replace sequence s3;
create or replace sequence s4;

select $1 as input
    ,case 
        when $1 is not null then $1 
        else s1.NEXTVAL  
     end as logic_1
    ,iff( $1 is not null, $1, s2.NEXTVAL ) as logic_2
    ,nvl($1, s3.NEXTVAL ) as logic_3
    ,coalesce($1, s4.NEXTVAL ) as logic_4
from values 
    (null),(null),(1000),(1001),(null),(null),(1002);
```

and the results all show incrementation.

[image]

Which, once I think more about this, needs to happen this way, if you are going to loop over rows in a parallel fashion, how do you allocate space to each block without becoming overlapped. You allocate a value per row, always. Which explains what is most likely happening here.

So Lukasz solution is very clever to avoid "making rows" you know you don't wanted to be created.

Another, is purely a logical point, that sequences can and will have gaps even in Lukasz style solution. They are not a gap free number set.

So that leaves the idea of "waste". Given NUMBER can hold 64bit numbers just fine, and unix epoch had a second for ~138 years, you could allocate 4 billion sequences for 130 years, and not exhaust the value space. And the size of the value has no meaningful storage implications. You can just use Sequence values, carefree.